# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in Laravel blade template

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am passing an array in Laravel blade template from controller. But it shows an error

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Here is the array which I passed to the view

> [[{"id":10,"user_id":4,"service_speciality":"4","contact":"789","created_at":"2018-06-06 05:52:22","updated_at":"2018-06-06 05:52:22","branch_id":3,"name":"lene","doctor_email":"lene@gmail.com","service_name":"Tooth pain"}],[{"id":8,"user_id":4,"service_speciality":"1","contact":"123","created_at":"2018-06-06 05:51:41","updated_at":"2018-06-06 05:51:41","branch_id":1,"name":"lene","doctor_email":"lene@gmail.com","service_name":"Kneck pain"}]]

Here is my blade template view where I got error

```
@foreach($doctor as $datum)
<div id="pg-112-0" class="panel-grid panel-no-style col-lg-12">

@foreach($datum as $data)
<div id="pgc-112-0-0" class="panel-grid-cell col-lg-4">
  <div id="panel-112-0-0-0" class="so-panel widget widget_pw_person_profile widget-person-profile panel-first-child panel-last-child" data-index="0">

    <div class="person-profile h-card">

      <div class="person-profile__container">
        <div class="person-profile__basic-info">

          <h4 class="person-profile__name  p-name">
            <a href="{{ url('/doctor/'.str_slug($data["name"], "-").'-'.$data["id"] ) }}">
              Dr. {{ $data['name'] }}                                           
            </a>
          </h4>
          <div class="person-profile__label">
            {{ $data['service_name'] }} Specialist
          </div>
        </div>

        <a class="btn  btn-secondary  btn-block  person-profile__button" href="{{ url('/doctor/'.str_slug($data["name"], "-").'-'.$data["id"] ) }}" target="_self">Read More</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach

</div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: $data['service_name'] should be  $data->service_name, etc, etc.

Comment: Message is clear, isn't it?

Comment: use $var->property it will work

Comment: @u_mulder...ya message is clear.... i got that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error massage says it all. Change your code from:

```
$data['SOMETHING']
```

To

```
$data->SOMETHING
```

Example from: `$data['service_name']` to `$data->service_name`